# Can someone explain S3 bucket privacy settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So this is yet another question in my ongoing effort to understand AWS. Can anyone explain the s3 bucket privacy settings and how Block public access interacts with the CORS, ACL and Policy settings. I find their descriptions less than straight forward.

For instance if I wanted to use CORS to control the types of requests and a Policy to limit IAM access to certain users should I have blocked all public access on or off, and should I have any of the sub options set to on? Also, if I have Block public access is off do I need to worry about everything being public or are the CORS and Policy settings now gating access?

Total AWS Noob, thanks in advance.

Comment: ACL, APM came from something else i was working on.

Comment: Read this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/. Don't use ACLs unless you need to. CORS has nothing to do with access from authenticated IAM principals. Enable BPA unless you need some of the objects in the bucket to be made available to unauthenticated clients (e.g. a web page).

Answer (score 1):

Following the [aws s3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html)

```
By default, new buckets, access points, and objects don't allow public access. 
However, users can modify bucket policies, access point policies, or object permissions to allow public access. 
S3 Block Public Access settings override these policies and permissions so that you can limit public access to these resources.
```

Apparently the "feature" is trying to address a very common and serious cloud vulnerability - too permisive user-defined policies.

So basically it is an extra policy denying unauthenticated access. Deny overrides Allow in policies, so even if someone accidently or "accidently" allows public/unauthenticated access to an S3 object, the owner can specify that any unauthenticated access is denied.

Comment: So long story short, if Block all is on it overrides everything, if off, then you get to control security. Buckets we want to be interacted with by outside user's via REST or somthing should have Block all off and a carefully crafted ACL, Policy, & CORS. Buckets we never want to even have the chance of being public should have Block all on.

Comment: @aris-t block all doesn't block all, just unauthenticated access. If you allow access using different IAM or bucket roles, then the access is allowed (I'm not sure how access through the cloudfront distribution is considered). Btw: CORS is actually used for client-side permissions,not controling access to the S3 objects.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into CORS on my own, yea it wasn't what i thought it was. If i may switch the question a bit, how should an s3 bucket be configured to allow presigned uploads via post request? Right now I have it working but i have block all set to off. Can i still do a presigned post with block all on?